# Problem adding details to the top part of a model using boolean

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make this lantern here but I can't figure out how to make the details in the top part (Circled in red).

[image]

And this is the 3D view:

[image: 3D View of the top part]

I have also tried using the boolean modifier but this strange artifacts on the edges of the boolean area appears:

[image]

So, is there any other way to make this without using boolean or am I doing the boolean operation wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it this way but I used a higher topology:

[image]

Comment: I am still getting the strange artifacts regardless if i made all the faces quads, is there any other method that you could suggest? (I am using blender 2.8 btw if that helps)

Comment: you should not have any artifacts, perhaps share this part of your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Here is the .blend file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XUL4NZ57xZ71oRRaCy3QfmFHDBIShFD5   (Apologies, I was having trouble uploading the file to blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)

Comment: please share the version with the problem  ;)  (with the artifact, after applying the boolean)

Comment: It's on the file, just hidden. It should be inside the scene collection, collection and it is labelled "Top Part Boolean Test".

Comment: oh ok your problem is that you had to recalculate the normals

Comment: Ohhh... That immediately fixed it. Thank you so much for your help.